# neo-tree.nvim cuts file/directory automatically when switching buffers

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I started using [neo-tree.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim) and something weird is happening.

I have a mapping that toggles neo-tree when I do n. All this mapping does is: `Neotree filesystem reveal right toggle<CR>`

After opening a file (i.e., using  on the desired file) in Neotree, the file is opened in a buffer on the left side. So far, so good! However, when I execute something like <`C-w> l` to go back to the Neotree panel, the file is automatically cut. If I execute any `<C-w> motion` the result (i.e., cutting) is the same. Why? Can someone please help me!? I just wanna switch/change buffers without any file operations.